# Cursor at wrong position when resizing EditText with animateLayoutChanges

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a design where there is an input `EditText` with a set of options for input units (`RadioGroup` full of `RadioButtons`). When the user selects a certain option, I have implemented `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` to adjust the width to the required value.

Everything works fine normally, but when I add `animateLayoutChanges` to improve the overall appearance, the cursor in the `EditView` is negatively affected:

- The user inputs a value, everything appears normal (gravity is right in the `EditText` by the way)
- The option that shrinks the view is checked - the view animates shrinking properly - BUT - the entry is now out of sight! Hidden where it should have been. If you click into the field or change the `RadioButton` option to one with the same size input, the entry then moves to the appropriate position...
- Similarly - the view is small and has an entry in the correct position, an option where the view expands is chosen - now the view expands and the entry is left in the centre of the view instead of moving to the right position! Again it refreshes when another action regarding the `EditText` is performed..

I have attempted to fix this by:

- Storing the input string into a temporary variable and replacing it with `setText()`
- Using `append("")` to add nothing prior to re-adding the string
- Calling `.requestFocus()` in the `EditText` upon selection
- Redrawing the view with `.invalidate()`
- Setting the cursor to the end of the view
- Attempting to custom-set animations (without success, I may have to continue with this approach?)

If anyone knows how I can potentially refresh the view so that it updates the text position or otherwise disable the animation on just this view whilst retaining all of the others that would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your sample code in order to understand what you are trying to attempt and not working?

Comment: Hi, sure I can but I don't see how it will help - none of the above methods refresh the view such that it changes the cursor position.. I just need a way to refresh it after the end of the animateLayoutChanges animation.. I tried setting it to check the end of the animation programmatically but that uses a layouttransition and not an animation.

Is there something in the question you don't understand?

Comment: I had a similar issue where an EditTexts cursor position would cause the EditText to be off center and cut off after a view change with animateLayoutChanges="true". It seems like the gravity="center" was part of the issue. Centering the EditText via constraints in constraint layout and removing gravity center resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up working out a solution after all..! Here it is for those who may be in a similar situation. I set animateLayoutChanges to false and custom animated the other transitions - in my case it was TextViews next to the EditText that were appearing and disappearing as it changed size. I had to use the .animate().alpha(float) method as below.

For becoming visible:

```
textViewFractionIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
textViewFractionIn.animate()
    .alpha(1.0f)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            // Has to be blank it seems to override the previous .setListener in the GONE case?
            }
        });
```

And for making it invisible (GONE in this case):

```
textViewFractionIn.animate()
    .alpha(0.0f)
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            textViewFractionIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

This animates the fading of views as per default, but any movements of the views remain discrete and thus the EditText cursor remains in the right spot!